# How to compile some java files in to a bin directory from my Java app?

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I have a Java app need to dynamically compile Java files from a src directory into a bin directory with a lib directory :

The structure looks like this :

```
Dir_Result
  src
  lib
  bin
```

The project copies 2 directories src and lib from Dir_Origin to Dir_Result, it then programmatically changes some Java files in the Dir_Result/src and compiles them into Dir_Result/bin

Usually I use Netbeans to compiles projects, but now I need to write Java code to do the compiling for me. I've tried the following approach, it went through without error. Yet I don't see anything in the bin directory. No errors and no output.

```
runCommand("javac -d C:/Dir_Result/bin/ -cp C:/Dir_Result/lib/* C:/Dir_Result/src/*");

...

  public static String runCommand(String Command)
  {
    String Line,Result="";
    Process Child;

    try
    {
      Child=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c "+Command);
      Result+="Executing : "+Command+"\n";      
      BufferedReader Input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Child.getInputStream()));
      while ((Line=Input.readLine()) != null) Result+=Line+"\n";
      Input.close();
      Result+="Done\n";
    }
    catch (IOException e) { Result+=e.toString(); }

    return Result;
  }
```

I'm not sure what went wrong, how to fix it ? If I need to setup classpath, how to do it within my program, or is it doable from runCommand ?

Comment: I ran your code , it's producing compiled file.

Comment: Plz check ``Dir_Result/bin`` is exists or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why, it's because some of my Java files has some characters in a different encoding, so I added "-encoding ISO-8859-1" and it worked.